# Vim Regex Search with Alternatives

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to match a string with a list of alternatives. When I do

```
echo "vimNotFunc" =~ "\vnot"
```

I get `1`, as expected. However, if I the same regex, but add an alternative, I get `0` :

```
echo "vimNotFunc" =~ "\vnot|string"
```

From the help files, I should not have to escape `|`. Should that match return `1` (`true`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using strings between double quotes, so you must double backslashes, like:

```
:echo "vimNotFunc" =~ "\\vnot|string"
```

It is simpler to use single quotes, and avoid this issue, like:

```
:echo "vimNotFunc" =~ '\vnot|string'
```

However, I don't know how your first regex works. It does not work in my `vim`. It's not expected result for me.

Comment: Thanks! The first one should be `"not"` without the `\v`.

Comment: Whether or not it matches depends on the value of the `'ignorecase'` option.  See `:help 'ic'` and `:help =~`.  (Assuming that, as @Birei says, you use double backslashes or single quotes.)